# general term for wheat, barley, oat, rye

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, plantas

What would you call the thing on this image?

> [image]

I am looking for the general term or hypernym, I know that it has more types:

- wheat
- barley
- oat
- rye

My suggestions: trigo de maiz, plantas de cereales

Comment: The plant on the image is wheat that is translated as "trigo". It's not really clear what you are asking for. If you want a word that could describe all the different plants you mentioned in english in the question, given that they are all cereals, I'd use "cereal" or "grano". "Cereal" is more correct in my opinion, since things like garbanzo and beans are called "grano" too, but are not cereals. That's all in Spain.

Comment: I think in fact it is barley, but I agree _cereales_ is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessary to say *plantas de cereales*. **Cereales** alone is enough. For example, when you say "un campo de cereales" you're implicitly understood to mean "un campo de *plantas de* cereales".

You can also say:

- granos
- gramíneas